# Convert file from one CSV format to another

Tags: python, csv

I have two CSV files. When I open them with Notepad++, I see the differences between them.

This is the first CSV file:

```
"Type"  "Id"    
"Task"  "170033"    
"Task"  "170256"    
"Task"  "170263"
```

This is second CSV file:

```
Type,Id 
Task,170033  
Task,170256  
Task,170263
```

What is the difference, and how can I change the first one to the second one using Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with the built-in Python library `csv`:

```
import csv

with open('out.csv', 'w') as csvfile_write:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile_write, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n')

    with open('in.csv') as csvfile_read:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile_read, delimiter=' ', quotechar='"')

        for row in reader:
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: You may want to use csvformat command-line tool provided by csvkit 3rd party Python library (install via `pip install csvkit`). In your specific example, use this command: `csvformat -t -q '"'  -D "," -U 3  -Q "" first.csv > second.csv` in command-line.

Answer (score 0):

The first file is space separated and each item quoated.
The second file is comma separated.
To convert just use the following code:

```
out = open('02.csv','w')

with open('01.csv') as f:
  for line in f:
    new_str = ','.join(list(map(lambda x: x.strip('"'),line.split())))
    out.write(new_str + "\n")

out.close()
```

1. Just create a new file
2. Open the first file and iterate through line
3. convert each line, split fields, strip quoates, and join them again
   with comma
4. Write result to new file
5. Don't forget to close the writable file at the end